# Error while compiling the project

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm getting this error everytime I try to compile my program.

> Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed
>   project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
>
> The "DebugType" parameter is not supported by the "XamlCTask" task.
>   Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public
>   instance property.
>
> The "XamlCTask" task could not be initialized with its input
>   parameters.

It's an Android Project on Xamarin.

Thanks to everyone In advance.

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build log.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, use menu option : Tools > NuGet package manager > NuGet packages for solution. In outer right column of popping up packages and list, choose the Xamarin.Forms package and installing that latest version, rebuild the project.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I had two instances of VS 2017 running. First instance had Xamarin default project with old Nuget for Xamarin. Ran debug onto Mac build server.

Then started up second instance of VS with Xamarin project on latest Nuget for Xamarin. Both instances were connected to MAC build server. When I tried to build I would get this error.

Stoped both instances of VS and started just one. Loaded my project with the latest Xamarin Nuget - All builds OK now.

Comment: I had just one instance of VS running but still getting the same error. I closed VS and reopened and the error disappeared.